# Draw a graph from a dynamic table using jquery, js and cal(x)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I design a selftracking frontend where participants enter numbers into a frontend. Whilst these are written into a database I want them to be instantly visualized. To do some calculations I use calx a jquery plugin (which allows for excel like computing). So I have form fields like:

```
<td><input name="name1" type="text" id="cc3" size="10" data-formula="($bb3/$aa3)*100">
```

data-formula presents the box then with a value. I now want to visualize this value (here in percent) as a bar (like a progressbar described here http://jsfiddle.net/Z6k3C/).

The Problem is, that I only have started working with js and jquery and I cannot figure out how I can parse the value from data-formula into the following code snippet so the bar changes dynamically with the entered numbers (not on click, on change)

```
$(function() {
var colors = [];
$("#slider").slider({
    max  : 200,
    value: 10,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        colors = (ui.value < 20) ? ['#f00','#000'] : ['#ff0','#000'];
        colors = (ui.value > 50 && ui.value < 100) ? ['#080','#fff'] : colors; 
        colors = (ui.value > 100) ? ['#808','#fff'] : colors;
        $(".ui-progressbar-value").css({'width' : ui.value + "%", 'backgroundColor' : colors[0] });
        $(".ui-progressbar-text").css('color', colors[1]).text(ui.value + "%");
    }
});
```

I hope you do understand my problem and I hope for your help.

Kind regards,
Jon

Answer (score 0):

You can use `keyup()` for `input` to get value after every key pressed

See: http://jsfiddle.net/Z6k3C/78/

I had to add `change` function to `slider` to dynamicly change progressbar.